# Excel VBA Userform - Execute Sub when something changes on dynamic comboBox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I created a userform where is a comboBox
Depending which result user chooses, new comboBoxes will appear with new choices to choose from.
Below is the latest test I tried.

How do I make it so that when user changes the value in the new comboBox it will execute a premade function/sub

Code in Form

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim structSheet As Worksheet
Dim tbCollection As Collection


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim ignoreList(3) As String

    ignoreList(0) = "main"
    ignoreList(1) = "configurator"
    ignoreList(2) = "create structure"
    Set WB = Excel.ActiveWorkbook

    For Each sheet In WB.Worksheets
        If Not isInTable(ignoreList, sheet.Name) Then
            supercode_box.AddItem sheet.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub supercode_box_Change()
    If Not sheetExists(supercode_box.text) Then Exit Sub
    Set structSheet = WB.Worksheets(supercode_box.text)

    'Dim obj As clsControlBox

    topPos = 10
    leftPos = 54
    ID = 1

   ' For ID = 1 To 2
        Set ComboBox = createProductForm.Controls.add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
        With ComboBox
            .Name = "comboBoxName"
            .Height = 16
            .Width = 100
            .Left = leftPos
            .Top = topPos + ID * 18
            .AddItem "test"
            .Object.Style = 2
        End With

        Set tbCollection = New Collection
        tbCollection.add ComboBox

    'Next ID
End Sub
```

code in class1 module

```
Private WithEvents MyTextBox As MSForms.controlBox

Public Property Set Control(tb As MSForms.controlBox)
    Set MyTextBox = tb
    MsgBox ("did it get here?")
End Property

Public Sub comboBoxName_Change()
    MsgBox ("start working ffs")
End Sub

Public Sub comboBoxName()
    MsgBox ("?? maybe this?")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging on your code, the easiest way is to write the value you need in a separate worksheet.

Then make a check, whether it is changed and if it is changed, write the new value and fire the procedure that you want.

In short, something like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    If Worksheets("Special").Cells(1, 1) = WB.Worksheets(supercode_box.Text) Then
        Call TheSpecificSub
    End If

    Worksheets("Special").Cells(1, 1) = WB.Worksheets(supercode_box.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: How does that help me?
How do I add TestMe() sub to ComboBox I yet don't have?